# Bootstrap mobile responsive pages

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

While using Bootstrap, is there another way to make the mobile-first responsive web page other than using the viewport meta tag?

```
<meta name=viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is developed to be mobile-first. You don't have to do anything to enable mobile-first design with Bootstrap. But it is recommended by Bootstrap to add the meta-tag [as described in the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#responsive-meta-tag):

> Bootstrap is developed mobile first, a strategy in which we optimize code for mobile devices first and then scale up components as necessary using CSS media queries. To ensure proper rendering and touch zooming for all devices, **add the responsive viewport meta tag** to your `<head>`.
>
> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

The `viewport` meta-tag is also commented as required meta-tag on the [starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template).

Comment: I was going to post a similar answer.  Will just add that @media queries are the optimal way to go in today's standards.  As well, one should keep in mind that the search starts on a mobile size, yet most sales are fulfilled on larger screens, as per Google reports.